# How to get site URL if database is disconnected?

Tags: database, redirect, debug

Recently I realized that you could include a db-error.php file in your `wp-content` directory from "[How to monitor server for error establishing a database connection](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/239310/how-to-monitor-server-for-error-establishing-a-database-connection)" that would replace the existing WordPress database error message with something custom.  I thought about doing a redirect in db-error.php like:

```
header("Location: http://vader.com/saber.html");
exit();
```

but I wanted to replace `http://vader.com` with the site URL so this could be portable but after researching I didn't see a way to obtain the site URL without the connection and I per discussions I was told you want to do minimal modifications to the wp.config file.  Is there a way to get the site URL without a database connection that could be used in the header redirect?

Comment: You're right I said minimal but I didn't say none :-) In this case I think I'd use either the site URL override constant, or just a constant of your own if you don't want it to have any effect when the db is attached.

Comment: Or you could include saber.html instead of redirecting to it

Comment: Im thinking of this from a plugin development scenario and how I can get a redirect or even the db-error.php file there but that was going to be a second question but Im still testing the db-error.php as this made me want to figure out how to get the URL without the db first.

Comment: No db means no plugins though

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook but a plugin can write a file to setup this can it not?  Still researching it though

Comment: Ah yeh. Caching plugins do that. Then your plugin could check the URL in the file and update it if it's changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is setting the site's URL in the `wp-config.php` file itself. This effectively overrides the `siteurl` option that's otherwise stored in the database, but it also means you can reference the URL without doing a query.

From [the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Edit_wp-config.php):

> It is possible to set the site URL manually in the wp-config.php file.
>
> Add these two lines to your wp-config.php, where "example.com" is the correct location of your site.
>
> ```
> define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
> define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
> ```

After that, using code in a regular theme that checks the `siteurl` or `home` option will pull from the constant rather than the database (hence my note on the override above). But in your default error script, you can reference `WP_SITEURL` directly to build a redirect URL.

Comment: Is there no way to set a constant without manually adding it in the wp-config?

Comment: You need to add the `define` _somewhere_. Adding it to `wp-config.php` is the recommended place to put it so you're not hacking something else in WP core itself.

Comment: How would you call the constant in `db-error.php`?

Comment: I'd make it be the same thing. If you're loading `wp-config.php`, keep it stored as `WP_HOME` or `WP_SITEURL` then reference it in `db-error.php`. If you want a non-standard constant, just drop it in `db-error` and call it whatever you need. A custom, non-standard name won't have any meaning to or impact on WordPress, so it wouldn't need to be in the `wp-config` file at all.

Answer (score 1):

Well the DB error has to come from the site requested. So why not just use the Superglobal $_SERVER and get the HTTP host.

```
header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ); //Redirect to root

exit(); //Exit
```

Answer (score 0):

WordPress relies on configuration to "tell" it what's the correct URL is. This might be database option or `WP_HOME` constant which overrides it. For a custom site it is common practice to set constant in `wp-config.php` and not bother with DB option altogether.

General case is more complicated since there is no dedicated WP API function (that I can remember) which makes it *determine* that information without configuration.

The closest routine I can think of in source is when `RELOCATE` mode is set, which explicitly tells WP that URL configuration is unreliable and should be updated from current state.

The relevant code in `wp-login.php` does following:

```
if ( defined( 'RELOCATE' ) && RELOCATE ) { // Move flag is set
    if ( isset( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] ) && ($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] != $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) )
        $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] = str_replace( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );

    $url = dirname( set_url_scheme( 'http://' .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ) );
    if ( $url != get_option( 'siteurl' ) )
        update_option( 'siteurl', $url );
}
```

So overall without access to configuration your remaining option is going to `$_SERVER` context, which is not too reliable.